# How to call the return values from the classes below to the above class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to call the return values of a function within a class (Second) to another class(First) using super(). The class - Second is below class First. The code is as follows

```
class First(Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num1 = 1
    
    # add num
    def add_nums(self):
        print(self.num1 + self.set_num2()) 


class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num2 = 2

    # Set num2
    def set_num2(self):
        return self.num2

a = First()
a.add_nums()
```

This actually works. However, if I add another class - Third below Second and call it in the class First, it doesn't work.

For instance, the following code doesn't work

```
class First(Second,Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num1 = 1
    
    # add num
    def add_nums(self):
        print(self.num1 + self.set_num2() + self.set_num3()) 


class Second:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num2 = 2

    # Set num
    def set_num2(self):
        return self.num2


class Third:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num3 = 3
    
    def set_num3(self):
        return self.num3

a = First()
a.add_nums()
```

Comment: The `__init__` method of `Second` should call `super().__init__()`

Comment: Even in your first case, I can’t get it to run in a jupyter notebook.

Comment: By the way, having a method called `set_num2` that sets nothing and *returns* num2 is a horrible design.

Comment: Even though `Second` doesn't extend any classes, it should still call `super().__init__()` to allow any of its own subclasses to work. To understand how this works, you can google "python method resolution order".

Comment: Your first code does *not* work, because `Second` isn't defined yet when you try to define `First`.